# What's the difference of Launch via NPM and Launch via npm in Visual Studio Code debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

[image]

There are two types of configurations in vscode debugging,

Launch via NPM and Launch via npm

I tried but didn't find the docs anywhere

What's the difference between those?

```
      // #launch via NPM
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch via NPM",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script",
                "debug"
            ],
            "port": 9229,
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ]
        },
        // #launch via npm
        {
            "name": "Launch via NPM",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script",
                "debug"
            ],
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "pwa-node"
        }
```

Comment: create both of them and see what is the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get an answer from vscode dev: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127232

> There is no real difference: the launch config with the "port" attribute is contributed by the legacy node.js debugger and will disappear soon. The second launch config is more recent and comes from js-debug.
>
> Since the legacy debug configurations are automatically redirected to js-debug and since port 9229 is the default debug port anyway, there should be no differences.